# Convergence of $\iint _{\Bbb R^2} e^{-(x+y)^4}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm trying to determine wethere the following integral converges:

$$\iint _{\Bbb R^2} e^{-(x+y)^4}dxdy$$

I tried to substitute $u=x+y$, $v=x$ (is this diffeomorphism?) and got $$\iint _{\Bbb R^2} e^{-u^4}dudv$$ and this diverges. But according to wolframalpha, it should converge. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your substitution makes no sense, and neither does the second integral.

Comment: @zhw. It was a typo. I fixed it

Comment: You are correct.  It diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\iint _{\Bbb R^2} e^{-(x+y)^4}dxdy=\iint _{\Bbb R^2} e^{-r^4(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^4}rdrd\theta=\iint _{\Bbb R^2} re^{-4r^4\sin^4(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})}drd\theta=\iint _{\Bbb R^2} re^{-4r^4\sin^4\theta}drd\theta=\iint _{\Bbb R^2} e^{-4y^4}dxdy=\int_{\Bbb R}(\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-4y^4}dy)dx=\int_{\Bbb R}Kdx$$where $K$ is a positive real number so the integral doesn't converge at all. It is also clear from the sketch below:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, wrong.  $e^{-r^4 (\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))^4} \ne e^{-r^4} e^{- (\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))^4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback....I corrected it!